# Two routers are slowing down the internet?

Tags: networking, router, internet, wireless-router, internet-speed

I have 2 routers with 2 different internet providers, each wifi of them on a different channel.

Router A - 200 MBPS Down, channel 1

Router B - 50 MBPS Down, channel 6

So I have 2 questions:

1. If I turn off one router, the other one's internet is faster, why is that? (the routers are on different channels, as much as I know it shouldn't interfere because of that)
2. On router A, if I connect using a cable, I would get the full speed, but on WIFI I would only get 40-50 MBPS even when the device is close to the router. any ideas how to solve this? (mode is N)

Device Models:

Router A: F@ST 3284 (http://www.sagemcom.com/broadband/gateways/docsis-gateways/fst-3284/)

Router B: NB403

Both of the routers were given by the ISP.

Comment: What channels? Are they completely non-overlapping channels (1, 6, 11)?

Comment: But you don't say the channel widths. If you increased the channel width, channels 1 and 6 can still overlap. That's why I asked aare you sure the channels do not overlap.

Comment: both of them 20 Mhz @RonMaupin

Comment: You said it is 802.11n, and that is most likely using 40 MHz channels, unless you explicitly set 20 MHz. Another possibility is that they use 40 MHz unless they see the other, then switch to 20 MHz, slowing your throughput.. You should double-check that both are manually configured for 20 MHz. Try setting the one on Channel 6 to Channel 11.

Comment: Hey, the devices are connected on 802.11n but the actual mode is on 802.11b/g/n. Should I try changing it to 40 MHz? also, I've tried changing the channels, no difference

Comment: Why not swap one to 5GHz & avoid the issue entirely?

Comment: Because all of my network cards on the computers don't support 5GHz @Tetsujin

Comment: @AmiT177 - As to the reason, if you turn one of the routers off, the other is faster is due to the 2.4 GHz interference.  The solution is to use 5.0 GHz

Comment: @Ramhound even if the channels are different?

Comment: When nobody is using the other router it should make no practical difference if it is turned on or off. Have you measured the difference and what are the numbers?

Comment: How far apart are the two physically?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart about 3-5m from each other